# Where is python-dev installed and what impact does it have on anaconda 2

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've installed Anaconda2, and set it as the main path of python. So if I type `$ python` or `$ pip`, they are of Anaconda2.

And to use Tensorflow, I need to install python-dev and python-numpy using

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

Where are they installed, and do they have any relation with my Anaconda2? Or do they affect only the pythons pre-builtin in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: i think python-dev should be installed using apt-get because anaconda will falls and pip falls look to the environment packages if they can not find them in env....you can install tensorflow through pip and anaconda too

Comment: Also wondering about this. I'm installing opencv3.2 and it requires python-dev. When I run cmake it complains about missing some environment variables and I wonder if they are set when installing python-dev or something.

Comment: ok, but where is it installed ?